# Migrated blog, how do I migrate rss url?

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, ghost-blog, ghost

I migrated my blog/website from WordPress to Ghost.

Wordpress software put all rss feed info at `<domain>/feed.xml` and now my new site with Ghost has the rss feed info at `<domain>/rss/`

Problem is, despite implementing 301 redirect from `feed.xml` to `rss/` and placing an xml redirect in the content of the `feed.xml` file all the world’s rss readers (or at least Feedly and FeedReader) still look to the old feed.xml to find the site, because that is the URL that was subscribed to

XML redirect looks like this:

```
<redirect>
    <newLocation>
        my_domain_here/rss/
    </newLocation>
</redirect>
```

Deleting / hiding `feed.xml` doesn’t help. I'm not sure what to do, RSS readers (I've tested with Feedly and FeedReader so far) refuse to find the new RSS because they are subscribed to the old URL. I don't want to lose 100% of my subscribed users. Please advise! Thank you.

Comment: 403? Wouldn't you want a 301?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure that is even possible. Ghost does not operate with a file based structure like WordPress does. So putting `feed.xml` in a folder does nothing since Ghost will not show it.

I don't think what you want to do is possible without modifying Ghost or doing it through Ghost Apps that will come at some point.